# Create native android apk via command line only (makefile)

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

## Goal

Creating a native android apk:

- via `vim` & `Makefile` only
- no use of `gradle, ant, maven, android.mk` and all that other stuff

## Problem

- I already created a simple non-native android apk via command line that works well & plays on my *Samsung S7*.
- When I try `loadLibrary("hello")` a shared object then the `logcat` tells me it cannot find it.
- The `.so` file is definitely added via `aapt add hellojni.apk ./lib/arm64/libhello.so`

## Error report

```
08-25 16:56:30.959 15637 15637 W ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.example.hellojni-1/base.apk / 4.0 running in com.example.hellojni rsrc of package com.example.hellojni
08-25 16:56:30.969 15637 15637 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.hellojni-1/lib/arm64
08-25 16:56:30.969 15637 15637 W amo     : Trying to load shared library!
08-25 16:56:30.969 15637 15637 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 16:56:30.969 15637 15637 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.hellojni, PID: 15637
08-25 16:56:30.969 15637 15637 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hellojni-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.hellojni-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libhello.so"
```

---

## *UPDATE*

Solution in https://github.com/skanti/Android-Project-Command-Line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you specify here seems like the culprit:

```
aapt add hellojni.apk ./lib/arm64/libhello.so
```

I tried adding a bogus file to an APK using the same type of path and then listing the APK contents:

```
./aapt.exe add test.apk ./lib/libbcc.dll
./aapt.exe list test.apk
```

And got this in the output:

```
./lib/libbcc.dll
```

I.e. I ended up with a directory named `.` in the root of the APK, inside of which a `lib` directory was created, inside of which the `libbcc.dll` file was placed (I confirmed this by opening the APK with 7zip).

If I remove the `./`:

```
./aapt.exe add test.apk lib/libbcc.dll
./aapt.exe list test.apk
```

I get the correct results:

```
lib/libbcc.dll
```

(I tested this both via Windows cmd and MSys2, with the same results)

Comment: Great! Since some manual `aapt` invocations use `-k` which discards the path, it's difficult to see that the `./` part is to blame. For example:


`$AAPT add -v -k ./bin/MyApp.apk.unaligned ./bin/classes/classes.dex`